# C言語の配列に文字列をいれたいのですが

Tags: c

配列にテキストファイルから取ってきた文字列をいれたいのですが、

```
char memo[10], name[10], memomon[10], memoday[10], memoname[10][10];
while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %s %d", &mon, &day, name, &num) != EOF) {
   memomon[i] = mon;
   memoday[i] = day;
   memoname[i] = *name;
   memo[i] = num;
   i++;
}
```

この場合どうやったら文字列をすべてmemonameの中にいれられますか？

Answer (score 7):

そもそも一時変数に代入する必要がないので、私だったら

```
int i, memomon[10], memoday[10], memonum[10];
char memoname[10][10];
for (
    i = 0;
    i < 10 && fscanf(fp, "%d %d %9s %d", &memomon[i], &memoday[i], memoname[i], &memonum[i]) == 4;
    ++i
);
```

と書くと思います。もし一時変数を使用するならば、文字列に関しては `strcpy` でコピーすればいいんじゃないでしょうか。

```
strcpy(memoname[i], name);
```

**※ バッファオーバーフローを防ぐために、文字列のフォーマットには必ず `%9s` のように文字数を指定しましょう。**

Answer (score 2):

C言語では、
文字列(charの配列)を「=」演算子で代入(コピー)することができません。
最初は strcpy() 関数を使ってみるのが良いでしょう。

Comment: こちらの回答をきっかけにメタに投稿しました: http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/q/1515/30 ご意見あればぜひお寄せください。(ただ、メタへの参加には信用度が5点必要になりますので、他のQ&Aの投稿を通して信用度をためていただければ。)

Answer (score 1):

CertaiN さんの回答の補足になりますが、最終的な答えは「C言語の配列に文字列をいれたい」ですので

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "%d", mon);
```

snprintf を使って文字列化して下さい。

Answer (score 0):

現在も配列を`=`で代入することはできません。
しかし、配列を含む構造体は`=`で代入することができます。
※K&Rの頃は使えませんでした、ANSIになってからできるようになった気がしますが、定かではありません。

---

以下の方法ははっきりいって配列をコピーするときの王道ではありません。

### 経験の浅い方、勉強中の方は標準ライブラリを使う方がよいです。

memcpyよりも速いのではないかと予想して性能比較したことがあります、有意な差はありませんでした。
memcpyは非常に速かったです。※今はどうなっているか調べていません。

配列は、要素数を統一するうまい方法がありません。
define定数を使うのが定番ですが強要できないのが難です。
ヘッダファイルに定義する方法もありますが、ヘッダファイルに実体を定義するのは抵抗があります。
構造体であれば配列の要素数を含めて宣言できますし、ヘッダファイルに書いて共有するのは抵抗ありません。

#### 【配列を`=`で代入する例】

この例では配列s2をs1に代入しています。

（注意）char以外の配列の場合、アラインメントが保証されないため危険です。

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char s1[1024] = {0};
    char s2[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    typedef struct {
        char s[1024];
    } Txx;

    *((Txx *)s1) = *((Txx *)s2);  //配列を=で代入する

    printf("s1 = [%s]\n", s1);
    printf("s2 = [%s]\n", s2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: > memcpyは非常に速かった    -- 実装依存です。昔見たのは、CPUのブロック転送命令になってた。これ以上速いのはあり得ません。  ところで、マイナス付いている割には、コメント無いですね。なんで?

Comment: greenteaさんコメントありがとうございます。memcpyについてネットの覗いてみました。いろいろと面白そうな記事がありました。速度性能が問題になるようなシーンではまた勉強し直したいと思いました。※-2票の意味が未だに分かりません。memcpy、strncpy、sprintfなど転送サイズをプログラマに意識させるより、設計で配列のサイズを固定化して「代入」で転送した方がメモリ破壊のリスクが減り、品質面で有利だと考えていますが、それを上回るマイナスの見当がつきません。後から回答を調べる人の選択肢を増やすつもりで回答しましたが残念です。